# Extending QML with PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qml

I would like to write a QML Extension using only Python. I know how to do this in C++, but not in Python. Is this even possible? Here's a vague idea of what I'm looking for.

```
class NewToQML(QObject):
    Q_PROPERTY(int root READ num WRITE setNum NOTIFY numChanged REVISION 1)
```

And in test.qml:

```
import MyQmlAdditions 1.0
NewToQML {
    num: 7;
}
```

[edit]
I would like to use this QML addition to accomplish for instance changing the cursor when the mouse is over the graphical object (NewToQML).

Comment: As I said below, you can't do this with PySide, but you can accomplish cursor changes by signaling python to change the cursor, or by exposing a context object which has a PySlot that changes the cursor using PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer a while back [on nabble](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/PyQt-support-for-Qt-4-7-td1924578.html#a1924580) answered by Phil Thompson-5 with a good explanation/reasoning following by Giovanni Bajo.

Short answer: PyQt does not support qmlRegisterType as of 4.7 and earlier versions.

However, PySide does have this functionality as shown [here](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeExtensionPlugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the examples and demos with PyQt, the Minehunt demo provides a QML example. If you don't have it installed, download the [PyQt4 source](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and look in `examples/demos/declarative/minehunt`.

Comment: This works for exposing data objects to QML, but I'm not sure you can expose graphical objects to the QML in this way. Edited my question to make that part clear.